# Return type of a function returning a pointer? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, types, return

I have a simple class with a get function which will return a pointer to a `Node` object. When I am declaring the functions return type, what do I put?

Node.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

Node* Node::getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

Node.h:

```
#ifndef FLEXSTRING_H
#define FLEXSTRING_H

class Node {
    private:
        struct node {
            int data;
            node* next;
            node* prev;
        };

        typedef struct node* nodePtr;

    public:
        getNext();  
};

#endif
```

I thought it would just be a `Node` object pointer, like `Node*` but I am getting a `‘Node’ does not name a type` compilation error. What is the correct return type I should be using? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you `#include "Node.h"`?

Comment: Oh wow, that was stupid, no I did not. Thanks mate. Comment and I'll mark as solved

Comment: You also forgot the return type in the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.h, the return type of `getNext()` probably needs to be `Node *`.   You have not supplied any return type.

That would be consistent with the definition within Node.cpp.   Note that Node.cpp needs to `#include "Node.h"` before trying to define member functions of `Node`.

You probably also do not need to nest a `struct node` definition within the defintion of `struct Node` either.   However, if you insist on doing that, you need to decide what the `next` and `prev` members of `struct node` represent, and use them accordingly.   That might affect what the return type of `getNext()` needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write:

```
class Node
{
    Node * getNext();
}
```

In C and C++, just a declaration of type is enough to use it in a pointer (incomplete type)

Answer (score 1):

Try to include the Node.h header file in your cpp otherwise the cpp file doesnt know that Node is a class